# Estimating the (double) Riesz transform.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-transforms

I'm trying to verify the following estimate, which appears in a paper I'm reading. It seems I'm missing something easy, I just can't figure this out.

$\textbf{Background}:$

For a function $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (Schwarz class), define the (sometimes called double Riesz) transform:

$$R_{11}(f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\xi_1^2}{\|\xi\|^2} \hat{f}(\xi)~ e^{i\langle \xi, x\rangle} d\xi.$$

Define also the frequency projection operators $P_N$ by

$$\widehat{(P_Nf)}(\xi) = [\varphi(\xi/N) - \varphi(\xi/2N)]\hat{f}(\xi),$$

where $\varphi$ is a smooth function supported inside $B_2(0)$ and $\varphi \equiv 1$ on $B_1(0)$.

$\textbf{Estimate I want}:$

$$\|R_{11}(f)\|_{\infty} \leq \mathrm{const}. \sum_N \|P_Nf\|_{\infty},$$

where the above sum is understood to be over dyadic integers.

$\textbf{What I tried}:$

It seems that the double Riesz transform is not necessarily bounded on $L^{\infty}$, which is why this is a little tricky. Looking at the integral that defines $R_{11}(f)(x)$, we can write

$$R_{11}(f)(x) = \sum_N \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\xi_1^2}{\|\xi\|^2} \widehat{P_Nf}(\xi)~ e^{i\langle \xi, x\rangle} d\xi.$$

Now, if we could just use the inequality $\xi_1^2/\|\xi\|^2 \leq 1$ directly above, the desired estimate would follow. However, this is nonsense, since the above integral is complex-valued. Taking absolute values destroys the term $e^{i\langle \xi, x\rangle}$, so I don't know what else to do.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: On the off chance that you still use this site, would you please provide a reference for the paper you mentioned.